# Android - Update gridview image

Tags: android, gridview

I want to change a image within my gridview when returning from a activity. When `position == 0` is clicked it opens `Activity2.class`. I have a button in `Activity2.class` when it is clicked it returns to `Activity1.class` and this is when I want to replace the image of `position == 0`in the gridview.

ImageAdapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;


Integer[] mThumbIds;


public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
    this.mThumbIds=mThumbIds;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) { 
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_level_single, null, true);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.myImageView);

        holder.number = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.myImageViewText);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.image.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    if (position == 0) {
        holder.number.setText("1");
    }
    if (position == 1) {
        holder.number.setText("2");
    }
    if (position == 2) {
        holder.number.setText("3");
    }
    if (position == 3) {
        holder.number.setText("4");
    }

    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView image;
    public TextView number;

}

}
```

Activity1.java

```
public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);

    Integer[] mThumbIds = {

            R.drawable.ic_round, R.drawable.ic_round,
            R.drawable.ic_round, R.drawable.ic_round,
    };

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,mThumbIds));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Activity2.class);
                intent.putExtra("text1", getString(R.string.test));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

            }

        }
    });
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)

{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2
    if(requestCode==2)
    {
                    /*Change image at 0th position and pass array to ImageAdapter*/

        Integer[] mThumbIds = {

                R.drawable.ic_complete, R.drawable.ic_complete,
                R.drawable.ic_complete, R.drawable.ic_complete,
        };
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    }
}
}
```

Activity2.java

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btn_next_exercise;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
    btn_replace = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_replace);


    final Intent i = new Intent();
    btn_replace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent();                 
            setResult(2,intent);  
            finish();//finishing activity  
        }
    });

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Activity1.java

```
    public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridView gridview ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);

        private Integer[] mThumbIds = {

            R.drawable.ic_round, R.drawable.ic_round,
            R.drawable.ic_round, R.drawable.ic_round,
        };
         gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,mThumbIds));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Activity2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("text1", getString(R.string.test));
                     Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);  
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);// Activity is started with requestCode 2  
                }
            }
        });
       }

       // Call Back method  to get the Message form other Activity  
    @Override  
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
     {  
             super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
              // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  
               if(requestCode==2)  
               {  
                        /*Change image at 0th position and pass array to ImageAdapter*/

                        private Integer[] mThumbIds = {

                            R.drawable.ic_round1, R.drawable.ic_round,
                            R.drawable.ic_round, R.drawable.ic_round,
                        };
                   gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,mThumbIds));

               }  
      }  

    }
```

Activity2.java

```
    public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn_next_exercise;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
        btn_replace = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_replace);


        final Intent i = new Intent();
        btn_replace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent();                 
                setResult(2,intent);  
                finish();//finishing activity  
            }
        });

    }

    }
```

In Adapter , remove mThumbIds image array and pass mThumbIds when you set adapter in activity1 like this,

```
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,mThumbIds));
```

ImageAdapter:

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        Integer[] mThumbIds;
        public ImageAdapter(Context c,Integer[] mThumbIds) {
            mContext = c;
            this.mThumbIds=mThumbIds;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            final ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_level_single, null, true);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.image = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.myImageView);

                holder.number = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.myImageViewText);
                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.image.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            if (position == 0) {
                holder.number.setText("1");
            }
            if (position == 1) {
                holder.number.setText("2");
            }
            if (position == 2) {
                holder.number.setText("3");
            }
            if (position == 3) {
                holder.number.setText("4");
            }

            return convertView;
        }


        private static class ViewHolder {
            public ImageView image;
            public TextView number;

        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm getting a error in activity1 at `gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,mThumbIds));` when I add the `mThumbIds`

Comment: Still getting a error at `gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,mThumbIds));`  warning error--- `ImageAdapter (Context) in ImageAdapter cannot be applied to (Activity1, java.lang.integer[])`

Comment: add Integer[] mThumbIds in your ImageAdapter constructor 

public ImageAdapter(Context c,Integer[] mThumbIds) {
            mContext = c;
            this.mThumbIds=mThumbIds;
        }

Comment: In Activity2 at `setResult(2,intent)` is it possible to do it with startActivity `intent.setClass(Activity2.this, Activity1.class);`  `setResult(2);` `startActivity(intent);`?

Comment: May be not check once, above given code is working for you?

Comment: You get result in onActivityResult ?

Comment: All that happens when I click the button is Activity2 closes and Activity1 displays again as it was.

Comment: Activity1.java: print log onActivityResult and check you get requestCode=2 or not.    

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   Log.d("TAG","onActivityResult:"+requestCode);
 }

Comment: Add your new whole Activity1 .java class

Comment: All I changed in activity1 was onActivityResult ---- `@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d("TAG", "onActivityResult:" + requestCode);
    } `